# Beginner WordPress site navigation

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, content-management-system

I'm new to tinkering with the WordPress back end and was wondering about a few things.

1> how can I make a menu with one multi level drop down menu 
e.g. categories > a / b / c > (1/2/3)

2>
a> what is the difference between using categories and tags? 
b>I also noticed you can state a slug for both, as well as state the exact same slug (and name) verbatim in tags and categories, so if a post shares the same tag/category will it cause the url to have a both slugs 
e.g. cateogy A's slug = a / Tag A's slug = a
post with category and tag both A has url blog.com/aa

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it's via the Custom Link option on the side of Menu Customization page.

Answer (score 0):

1. in apperance > menus, drag the submenu item below the main menu item, make sure to displace it a little bit to the right. If you don't want to assign a link to e.g. categories, just give it a custom link of #
2. **Categories** are not the same as tags, they're the **topic** under which your post can be classified. Each post shouldn't be classified under more than 2-3 categories, and usually one category is a sub of other.

   **Tags** refer more to what **components** your post contains, more like hashtags in social networks. Well just like hashtags, you need be selective and reasonable; up to 5 tags is acceptable.

   **Slugs** are post names, these are what links in address bar, or **permalinks** (settings > permalinks) will include if you choose post name, day and name, or month and name. For SEO, it is recommended that you choose one of these three options.
3. Neither tags nor categories are classically included in a post link, I suggest that you take alook at `yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`. links are generally `yoursite.com/tag/nice` or `yoursite.com/category/nice`, respectively.